# How do i write a regular expression to capture a word after a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, numbers, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm having an issue writing a regular expression.  I want to write an expression that will parse a string, looking for a positive number and then the first word that follows the number, whether or not there's a space or other type of word boundary between the number and the next word.  So I tried

```
2.4.0 :006 > str = "2g"
 => "2g" 
2.4.0 :007 > str.match(/\W?(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\W*(^[0-9:\/]+))/)
 => nil
```

but as you can see no matches occur.  I would expect the match to capture the "2" and then the "g".  Similarly, if I have a string like

```
2.4.0 :008 > str = "12.2 word next"
 => "12.2 word next" 
2.4.0 :009 > str.match(/\W?(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)\W*(^[0-9:\/]+))/)
 => nil
```

I expect the regex to capture the "12.2" and then the next word "word".  But as you can see my regex isn't cutting it.  How do I fix it to capture what I need?

Comment: trying to select "12.2word" or "12.2 word" in "12.2 word next" ?

Comment: I would like to have something that selects an array -- the first element being the number, "12.2" and teh second element being the word, "word" (i.e. ["12.2", "word"])

Comment: You can find it in my edited answer @Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to select "12.2word" or "12.2 word" in "12.2 word next" ?

As you replied in comments, to have float number in group1 and word in group2:

```
 (\d+\.\d+|\d+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+)
 Full match 6-15    `12.2 good`
 Group 1.   6-10    `12.2`
 Group 2.   11-15   `good`
```

---

My first Answer was:

```
 (\d+(\.\d{0,})?)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+)
 for " 12.2 good "
 Full match 6-15    `12.2 good`
 Group 1.   6-10    `12.2`
 Group 2.   8-10    `.2`
 Group 3.   11-15   `good`
```

Group1 is your integer part and Group2 is null or equal to .2 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

```
([0-9.]+)\s(\w+)
```

Input:

```
12.2 word
```

Output:

```
12.2
word
```

Ruby Code:

```
re = /([0-9.]+)\s(\w+)/
str = '12.2 word'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/ncVEAT/1

Comment: Although this works on "12.2 word" it doesn't work on "12.2-word next" or "12.2word next" ,both of which I woudl want to have "12.2" as the first matching eleemnt and "word" as the second matching element.

Comment: Use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `\s` @Dave

Comment: this regex matches `1.2.27 word` does `1.2.27` is your accepted match?